# Maven clean install failed to execute goal on project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am developing a spring boot project which has few modules. I have on entry point module which has main class, the other module dependencis i have added in entry point module pom.xml. When i give command mvn clean install it throws an error saying `

> Failed to execute goal on project api: Could not resolve dependencies
>   for project com.nikesh:api:jar:1.0.0: The following artifacts could
>   not be resolved: com.nikesh:lib:jar:1.0.0, com.nikesh:repo:jar:1.0.0,
>   com.nikesh:entity:jar:1.0.0, com.nikesh:dto:jar:1.0.0,
>   com.nikesh:service:jar:1.0.0, com.nikesh:common:jar:1.0.0: Failure to
>   find com.nikesh:lib:jar:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
>   was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
>   -`

**This is my pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.nikesh</groupId>
<artifactId>api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<description>api module</description>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.nikesh.api.MultiModuleApp</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nikesh</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nikesh</groupId>
        <artifactId>repo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nikesh</groupId>
        <artifactId>entity</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nikesh</groupId>
        <artifactId>dto</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nikesh</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nikesh</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please help me out resolving this issue.

Comment: You need to make sure that all sub modules are built in proper order before the main module build.

Comment: So this pom is one of your module's pom ? Where are the missing jars ? are they modules of your project ? from where are you running your mvn clean install command ? (remark : you don't have to use maven-compiler-plugin, it is included in the spring-boot-maven-plugin)

Comment: which maven _command_ have you issued ? I guess you have to install those dependencies before you will able to compile the `com.nikesh.api` artifact

Comment: a follow up on what @Java said, maven reactor takes care of the build order but you have to make sure that your application has access to all the dependencies it needs (as a sub module or via your local repo at least)

Comment: I am running command mvn clean install which is on my app module which has start class and the pom which i have attached. How to build other modules? For example i did not run this command for any other modules. I have just updated the pom and run that command only in app module

Comment: @Java thank you.. That worked.. I had to install all the dependent modules first..

Comment: run `mvn` clean install on your parent project instead of running it on your "entry point" module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that **all sub modules are built** in proper order **before the main module build**.

**Guide to Working with Multiple Modules**

**The Reactor**

The mechanism in Maven that handles multi-module projects is referred to as the reactor. This part of the Maven core does the following:

1. Collects all the available modules to build
2. Sorts the projects into the correct build order
3. Builds the selected projects in order

Because modules within a multi-module build can **depend on each other**, it is important that The reactor sorts all the projects in a way that guarantees any project is built before it is required.

**The following relationships are honoured when sorting projects:**

- a project dependency on another module in the build
- a plugin declaration where the plugin is another modules in the build
- a plugin dependency on another module in the build
- a build extension declaration on another module in the build
- the order declared in the  element (if no other rule
  applies)

Note that only "instantiated" references are used - `dependencyManagement` and `pluginManagement` elements will not cause a change to the reactor sort order

for more [info](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). You can refer this [link](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) for a **sample** multi module maven project.